# Word 2010 conditional formatting with check box content control

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Is there a way to create a word form with check box content control, where only the required fields are editable once check box is selected?

For example

If checked box A, require these 6 questions to be answered.
If checked box B, require these 4 to be answered.

Comment: VBA or VSTO (or what)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a click event on the check box that you want to trigger the logic.

```
Private Sub CheckBoxA_Click()
    If CheckBoxA.Value = True Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
        CheckBox2.Enabled = True
        CheckBox3.Enabled = True
        CheckBox4.Enabled = True
        CheckBox5.Enabled = True
        CheckBox6.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
        CheckBox3.Enabled = False
        CheckBox4.Enabled = False
        CheckBox5.Enabled = False
        CheckBox6.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like code for activeX controls, not content controls.

Comment: By activeX do you mean built in windows forms using VBA?

Comment: I mean tht it looks like the VBA code you would use for a traditional ActiveX checkbox control hosted in the document surface, yes. What do you mean?